# Editar tema no WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

É possível editar um tema no WordPress sem que afete a estrutura do mesmo, e adicionar mais funcionalidades ao tema de terceiros?

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Comment: Até dava uma boa resposta. Se puder caprichar na pergunta, adicionando pesquisa, tentativas, problemas atuais, melhorava muito e tem chance de reabertura.

Comment: Eu até poderia caprichar na pergunta, mas quando faço uma pergunta muito complexa falam para simplificar quando faço perguntas óbvias e simples respondem mas votam negativo, aqui não é uma comunidade de ajuda a desenvolvedores?

Comment: Bruno, "comunidade de ajuda" não, não é não... É um site de Perguntas e Respostas com objetivo de construir uma biblioteca de alta qualidade para referência futura (os mil visitantes que vierem depois de você são mais importantes que você, verdade pura e crua). Se você não pode gastar 20 minutos pra escrever uma pergunta legal (de preferência mais que 20), eu não vou gastar 40 minutos pra escrever uma resposta bacana, cheia de referências, código de exemplo testado, etcetera e tal...

Comment: É só editar a pergunta explicando o que já pesquisou, que problema está enfrentando e o que tentou pra resolver. É sua função encontrar o equilibrio entre o complexo e o simples. A [help] taí pra te ajudar. Também pode pedir suporte no [meta].

Answer (score 1):

É possível editar o tema sim sem alterar a estrutura e as funcionalidades, mas não é o ideal porque todas as edições serão sobreescritas na próxima atualização do tema.

A melhor opção para editar temas é a indicada pelo WordPress: criar um  [tema filho](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Temas_Filhos). Os arquivos que existirem no tema filho substituem o tema principal e o WordPress usa do tema pai aqueles que não existirem no tema filho.

A única excessão é o arquivo `functions.php` que é lido primeiro no tema filho e depois no tema pai. Se o tema pai for bem escrito, você consegue sobreescrever qualquer função do functinos.php apenas redeclarando-a no tema filho.

Pra fazer o tema filho você pode usar o guia que tem no [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Temas_Filhos) ou então usar um plugin, procurando no repositório por "child theme".

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível.

Se depois de pesquisar muito por um tema você não encontrar a funcionalidade que precisa, será necessário editar tema do WordPress que você adquirir para que ele consiga realizar tais funcionalidades.

> Referência para edição de templates:

[**WordPress CODEX**](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt:P%C3%A1gina_Inicial)